# Trying to switch focus to another input field but browser automatically focuses "first" input field in form (Safari only)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, safari

My React web app is forcing focus to the first input field in a form even if I actively change it with my mouse (I can switch input fields by tabbing though).

So I've tried debugging just to find out what or where the problem is occurring. But I believe this might have something to do with HTML and how input fields work that I am not aware of or maybe some browser-specific functionality as this is only occurring in Safari and not Chrome.

The React app creates a list of input fields by using the code below. `Skills` is an array that by default has three empty strings in it like `["", "", ""]`.

The `Keyword` component is rendered as shown in the following code snippet.

```
{Skills.map((i, index) => {
   return (
      <Keyword
         key={index}
         value={i}
         type="text"
         className={css(inheritedStyles.formInput)}
         changed={e => onListChange(e, 'Skills', index)}
         clicked={e => onListRemove(e, index, 'Skills')}
       />
   );
})}
```

```
  render() {
    const { changed, clicked, value } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={value} className={css(styles.formInput)} type="text" onChange={changed} />
        <a href="#remove-skill-field" onClick={clicked}>
          <svg className={css(styles.removeKeyword)} viewBox="0 0 96 96">
            <path
              fill={this.props.color}
              fillRule="evenodd"
              d="M48,44.8180195 L85.5756764,7.24234308 L87.1666667,5.65135282 L90.3486472,8.83333333 L88.7576569,10.4243236 L51.1819805,48 L90.3089626,87.1269821 L91.8999529,88.7179724 L88.7179724,91.8999529 L87.1269821,90.3089626 L48,51.1819805 L8.87301788,90.3089626 L7.28202762,91.8999529 L4.10004711,88.7179724 L5.69103736,87.1269821 L44.8180195,48 L7.24234308,10.4243236 L5.65135282,8.83333333 L8.83333333,5.65135282 L10.4243236,7.24234308 L48,44.8180195 Z"
            />
          </svg>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

So I expect this to produce (by default) 3 empty input fields in a row which I can navigate freely between both with clicking and tabbing.

The three input fields do appear and are empty, however, when I try to click on the second or third input field, Safari automatically focuses the first input field.

Anyone got a clue as to why this is? All help is appreciated!